# The phrase "in duplicate"

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage, formality

What does the following statement mean ?

Admit card should be submitted in **DUPLICATE**.

a) 1 original & 1 photocopy.

b) Both originals.

c) Both photocopies.

Comment: The phrase _in duplicate_ just means that there should be two. It is completely indifferent to whether those two are originals or photocopies.

Comment: Poor drafting. Why would anyone expect you to necessarily possess a duplicate in the first place? Ought to be "**Copies of** Admit card should be submitted in DUPLICATE." Do **not** submit original for now!

Comment: This is also on the ELL stack https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/220018/the-phrase-in-duplicate